# How to check if a foreign-key is part of a many-to-many in the same model?

Tags: django, django-models

Here is a simplified version of my model:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='group_creator')
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Membership')

    def clean(self):
        if self.creator not in self.members.all():
            raise ValidationError('Creator should be part of this group.')
```

When I perform a full_clean() on an new instance of my model, it raises this Exception.

```
ValueError: 'Group' instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

I know it comes from my clean() method, but I can't figure out why I get this error. I've seen people having the same trouble as me, but never in their own model.

Any idea how to solve this?
Apologies for my english, it's pretty poor, I know. Maybe that's why I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can't check `self.members.all()` when the object has not been saved yet. It needs a primary key before it can lookup relationships to itself in the join table.

What you should be checking is `self.cleaned_data['members']`.

Comment: So I would need to have my own custom validation (via a form) to get this working in the admin?

Comment: Ack. Sorry. I saw `clean` and my brain instantly jumped to "form". However, in a sense, yes, this can only reliably be checked in a form. For your model's `clean` method, you can keep it and simply add a test for `self.pk is not None`, to ensure that it's only checked on an instance that has at least been saved once. But, there's no way to validate that on the first save from the model.